# Unit Testing using Moq

Tags: c#, .net, mocking

This is a method under my controller which is used to create dummy keys to encrypt the data in the application and store the same in the amazon s3 bucket.

```
public JsonResult SaveMasterKeys(string MekText, int Thismek)
        {
            string folderName = string.Empty, fileName = string.Empty;
            List<string> folderNameList = new List<string>();
            folderNameList.Add("Guard1");
            folderNameList.Add("Guard2");
            try
            {
                if (Thismek == 1)
                {
                    folderName = "Guard1";
                    fileName = "NewMek1.key";
                }
                else
                {
                    folderName = "Guard2";
                    fileName = "NewMek2.key";
                }
                AWSS3File aws = new AWSS3File();

                //aws.BucketExist(filePath);
                //aws.CreateFile(MekText, filePath);
                // Check Weather the Folder is exist or not

                if (!aws.CheckFolderExist(folderName))
                {
                    foreach (var item in folderNameList)
                    {
                        aws.CreateFolder(item);
                        if (item == "Guard1")
                        {
                            aws.CreateFileIntoS3((item == folderName ? MekText : ""), item, "NewMek1.key");
                            aws.CreateFileIntoS3("", item, "Mek1.key");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            aws.CreateFileIntoS3((item == folderName ? MekText : ""), item, "NewMek2.key");
                            aws.CreateFileIntoS3("", item, "Mek2.key");
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    aws.CreateFileIntoS3(MekText, folderName, fileName);
                }
                ViewData["SaveMessage"] = "Saved successfully.";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                XTP.Logger.LogCritical("XTP.Web.internaltools", ex.ToString());
                ViewData["SaveMessage"] = "Keys not updated successfully.";
            }
            return Json(new { success = true, value = ViewData["SaveMessage"] }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

And this is the TESTMETHOD I have written for the same

```
[TestMethod]
        public void MockAlways()
        {
            var mock = new Mock<AccountController>();
            JsonResult json = new JsonResult();
            //new { success = true, value = ViewData["SaveMessage"] }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            json.Data = new { success = true, value = "sa" };
            json.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;


            mock.Setup(x => x.SaveMasterKeys("ss", 1)).Returns(json);

            var controller = new AccountController();
            var result = controller.SaveMasterKeys("ss", 1) as JsonResult;

            Assert.AreEqual(mock.Object.SaveMasterKeys("ssxs", 1), result.Data.ToString());
        }
```

I am getting an invalid setup error. Is there a way to resolve this error?

Comment: Can you provide error details?

Comment: Sure it is - Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: x => x.SaveMasterKeys("ss", 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you misunderstood how to mock a controller's action. You are mocking it and then comparing it with the mocked controller. This is not a way to go(it is like checking whether `true == true`.

Basically this error means that Moq cannot override non-virtual member(it is self-explanatory). You should change method's signature to `virtual` to allow overriding it.

But - you shouldn't mock action like this. Instead you should mock its dependencies(services, contexts, gateways etc.) and check whether with known input values you can get expected results without mocking the action itself.

Comment: Thank You. I did try that and i no longer get the error.

Comment: I also have a question:Can we mock an action method or do we need an Interface or a dependency to mock?

Comment: @rohitraina As I mentioned - you shouldn't mock actions, you should mock its dependencies(in your case `AWSS3File`). You can moved them to the constructor and place in the field.